# How do I get SelectFirstNode to work consistently in Acumatica PXTreeView?

Tags: acumatica

I created a screen in Acumatica with a Filter at the top, that when changed, populates a PXTreeView. I have the property SelectFirstNode set to true. On first load the first node is selected correctly. However, if I click on the 4th node of the tree, then change the filter, it will load a new tree but the 4th node is already selected. (Normally this wouldn't be a big issue but there are other tables dependant on the selected node and they aren't being cleared properly)

I would expect it to select the first node when the tree was rebuilt. Is there a method I can call when the Filter changes that would completely clear and refresh the treeview so that when the tree is rebuilt the first node is selected?

ASPX file

```
    <DataTrees>
        <px:PXTreeDataMember TreeView="Tree1" TreeKeys="ParentID, LineNbr, CategoryNbr, DetailLineNbr" />
    </DataTrees>
    </px:PXDataSource>
```

ExampleInq.cs

```
    public SelectFrom<TreeNode>
        .Where<TreeNode.parentID.IsEqual<Argument.AsString>
            .And<TreeNode.lineNbr.IsEqual<Argument.AsInt>>
            .And<TreeNode.categoryNbr.IsEqual<Argument.AsInt>>
            .And<TreeNode.detailLineNbr.IsEqual<Argument.AsString>>>.View Tree1;

    protected virtual IEnumerable tree1([PXString]string parentID, [PXInt]int? lineNbr, [PXInt]int? categoryNbr, [PXString]string detailLineNbr)
    {
        if(parentID == null)
       {
           var parents = SelectFrom<Parents>
           .Where<Parent.parentID.IsEqual<Filter.parentID.FromCurrent>>.View.Select(this);
           foreach(var parent in parents>
           {
               //create new Treenode item
               yield return item
           }
        }
        else if(lineNbr == null)
        {
           //lookup and loop though next level
           yield return item
        }
        else if(categoryNbr == null)
        {
           //lookup and loop through categories
           yield return item
        }
        else if(detailLineNbr == null)
        {
           //lookup and loop through details
           yield return item
        }
     }
```

When I change Filter.parentID the tree1 delegate gets called and the tree is filled in correctly, but the selected node remains the one previously selected and doesn't return to the first node as expected.

Comment: I would expect to see your source code in order to give you advice

Comment: How are you populating the PXTreeView? Source code would help.

Comment: I’ll see if I can pull out all the relevant parts of the source code and post them. It might be quite lengthy.